# React Native -Android Device dark mode change the placeholder colour

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I use React Native paper in my Android App. I face a problem when I change the device theme to dark mode the input box placeholder colour changes. but it is visible correctly when I change the device theme(dark mode to light mode).

And I didn't set any theme colour in the App.

Please check the below image.

In Light Mode

[image]

In Dark Mode

[image]

Textinput.js

```
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import {TextInput as Input} from 'react-native-paper';

export default function TextInput({errorText, description, ...props}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Input
        textColor="#000"
        autoComplete="off"
        activeUnderlineColor="#000"
        returnKeyType={'next'}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        secureTextEntry={false}
        placeholderTextColor="#D50000"
        mode="flat"
        style={styles.input}
        {...props}
      />
      {description && !errorText ? (
        <Text style={styles.description}>{description}</Text>
      ) : null}
      {errorText ? <Text style={styles.error}>{errorText}</Text> : null}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderStartWidth: 0,
    borderEndWidth: 0,
    width: '100%',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#414757',
    paddingTop: 8,
  },
  error: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#f13a59',
    paddingTop: 8,
  },
});
```

I need your expertise help.